# Return Max Date to a property

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the last date from a table in a database. Please see the logic I have tried below but with no success.

Here is my class with a DateTime Property.

```
public class MyMaxDateClass
{
    public DateTime? MyMaxDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is the task where I am using LINQ to return the max date. To assign back to the property.

```
public async Task<MyMaxDateClass> GetMyMaxDateClassDateAsync()
{
    MyMaxDateClass myMaxDateClass = new();

    myMaxDateClass = await (from s in _databaseDbContext.MyTable
                        select s.DateColumn).MaxBy();

    return myMaxDateClass;
}
```

Please logic pasted above

[image]

If I had these 2 dates I'd expect it to return the latest one.

Comment: How can this compile, shouldn't `MaxBy()`  take an argument?

Comment: I _think_ you just want `Max` instead of `MaxBy` (and you don't need `new()` since you're just overriding the reference in the next line.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel my apologies but this doesn't compile, I am struggling to understand what I need to pass into the Max function. That's why I have shown what I have tried so far.

Comment: If you want the maximum value, use `Max()`. `MaxBy()` is when you want to get the object with the largest property (as selected by the delegate you pass to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use max and OrderByDescending

max

```
var myMaxDateClass = (from s in context.MyMaxDateClass select s.MyMaxDate).Max();
```

Generated query

```
SELECT MAX([m].[MyMaxDate]) FROM [MyMaxDateClass] AS [m]
```

OrderByDescending

```
 var S = context.MyMaxDateClass.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyMaxDate)
                               .Select(d => d.MyMaxDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Generated query

```
SELECT TOP(1) [m].[MyMaxDate] 
FROM [MyMaxDateClass] AS [m] ORDER BY [m].[MyMaxDate] DESC
```